# ¿mandar un valor a una ventana modal por la etiqueta <a>?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Mi problema es que tengo una etiqueta  que necesito que llame una ventana modal que muestre un pdf que tengo  alojado en una bd según el  id de cada etiqueta que le corresponda.

Mi etiqueta es esta

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM documentos WHERE id_tipo_doc = 1");
while($ro = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

echo "<a href='#'  onclick='modales(".$ro['id'].")' class='alado' id='ver-pdf' data-target='#modal' data-toggle='modal'><i class='fas fa-file-pdf'></i>   ".$ro['nombre']."</a>";
}
```

insertaría el modal aqui

```
<div id="mod" class="modal fade" role="dialog"></div>
```

y el  código para hacer la petición

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 // Asociar un evento al botón que muestra la ventana modal
function modales(id) {
   $.ajax({
       // la URL para la petición
       url : 'modalpdf.php',

       // la información a enviar
       data : { 'fac' : id},

       // especifica si será una petición POST o GET
       type : 'GET',

       // el tipo de información que se espera de respuesta
       dataType : 'html',

       // código a ejecutar si la petición es satisfactoria;
       success : function(respuesta) {
           $('#mod').html(respuesta);
       },

       // código a ejecutar si la petición falla;
       error : function(xhr, status) {
           alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
       },
   });
 };
});
</script>
```

este es el modal

```
div class="modal fade" id="mod">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="mod">nuevo</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            Mi modal

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            Footer modal
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿`data-target='#modal'` no debería ser `data-target='#mod'`? El id de tu modal es `mod`

Comment: buena observación, solo que aun no me aparece el modal!! solo  tengo uno sencillo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mandar un valor X desde una etiqueta a hacia un modal.
Puedes hacerlo usando los data attributes.

Te doy un ejemplo

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-elemento="12345" id="boton"> </a>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#boton").data("elemento"); // Esto debe retornar 12345
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: Gracias fue de  ayuda me sirvió  el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiar en tu funcion modales en el apartado del success lo siguiente:

```
success : function(respuesta) {
     var modal = $('#mod');
     modal.find('.modal-body').html(respuesta);
     modal.modal('show');
},
```

Comment: Si te funciona no es necesario ni el data-target ni el data-toggle en el link que tiene el evento de mostrar el modal

Comment: Buenas tardes. lo intento como me dices pero  me sucede lo mismo,  te explico,  al darle click al enlace solo oscurece la pagina como si fuese a mostrarlo pero no muestra el modal. no se si logre explicarme

Comment: elimina los atributos data-toggle y data-target de tu elemento <a> y en el success pon un alert antes de mostrar el modal como te mostre en mi respuesta a ver si llega a ese punto el ajax.

Comment: Al eliminar el data-toggle y target al dar click no hace nada. y al ponerlos me genera este  error 

Uncaught ReferenceError: modales is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM634 calidad.php:150)